# Migrating from MagentoGo

Tags: import, export

Would there be any tips or documentation of moving of the soon to be defunct magentogo to community edition?

Comment: you can export the data form the Magento Go and Import in Magento Community. but you have to create Attributes as well as images in new site

Comment: Just go for it, keep it simple (days to weeks), choose good hosting, choose a good theme, and use Cart2Cart to migrate (no affiliation - just very simple to use).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at:
[go.magento.com/migration/](http://go.magento.com/migration/)

or simply(if don`t have some sophisticated store) do export the CSV’s and uploading the same to the new store.